Spring boot CRON expression is not working
I use spring bootd and I want to run a CRON each Saturday at 10 am.
I decided to run the con every 10 minutes to see if the function was called.
@Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *")
public void validation () {
    System.out.println("heolooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");
}

When it is fixedRateit is working.
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1)
    public void consoleUserSqsListner() {
       System.out.println("heolooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo2");
    }

In my main I have:
@SpringBootApplication 
@EnableAsync 
@EnableScheduling 
public class MAppUserApplication {

Please what is the cause of this issue?
My version is 2.2.4.RELEASE
I noticed that in the component I have 3 scheduled, this is why the latest is not run. How to tell spring to run more scheduled ?

my version is 2.2.4.RELEASE

Your cron is working with Spring boot 3.3.1. fixedRate start running from the boot of the application, and @Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *") means "run at the top of every 10th minute". It aligns with the clock, not with the application start time. So, it will run at 00:00, 00:10, 00:20, etc., regardless of when your application started.
To show how it works wrote this class below
@Component
public class ScheduledJobForSomething {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledJobForSomething.class);

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void runeveryminute() {
        log.info("1 minute");
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/10 * * * *", zone = "GMT")
    public void runEvery10Minutes() {
        log.info("1-------------------10 minutes:{}", Instant.now());
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */10 * * * *", zone = "GMT")
    public void runEvery10Minutes2() {
        log.info("2-------------------10 minutes:{}", Instant.now());
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/60 * * * * *")
    public void runevery60seconds() {
        log.info("60 secs");
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60_000)
    public void consoleUserSqsListner() {
        log.info("fixed rate 60 seconds");
    }
}

logs looks like below
2024-07-06T12:40:00.014+01:00  INFO 11952 --- [scheduled-demo] [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1-------------------10 minutes:2024-07-06T11:40:00.014431600Z
2024-07-06T12:40:00.023+01:00  INFO 11952 --- [scheduled-demo] [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 2-------------------10 minutes:2024-07-06T11:40:00.023434400Z
2024-07-06T12:50:00.013+01:00  INFO 11952 --- [scheduled-demo] [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1-------------------10 minutes:2024-07-06T11:50:00.013555600Z
2024-07-06T12:50:00.014+01:00  INFO 11952 --- [scheduled-demo] [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 2-------------------10 minutes:2024-07-06T11:50:00.014555200Z

Reference:

Documentation: https://spring.io/blog/2020/11/10/new-in-spring-5-3-improved-cron-expressions#usage
Working example: https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/scheduled-demo

For SB 2.2.4 I changed the pom like below and ran mvn clean spring-boot:run same code worked without problem, you can see the logs below
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.github.ozkanpakdil</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduled-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scheduled-demo</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.4.RELEASE)

2024-07-07 12:14:02.366  INFO 15324 --- [           main] i.g.o.s.ScheduledDemoApplication         : Starting ScheduledDemoApplication on hp-envy-2021-i7-nvidia with PID 15324 (C:\Users\ozkan\projects\spring-examples\scheduled-demo-spring-boot-2.2.4\target\classes started by ozkan in C:\Users\ozkan\projects\spring-examples\scheduled-demo-spring-boot-2.2.4)
2024-07-07 12:14:02.368  INFO 15324 --- [           main] i.g.o.s.ScheduledDemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2024-07-07 12:14:02.971  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2024-07-07 12:14:02.981  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-07-07 12:14:02.982  INFO 15324 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.30]
2024-07-07 12:14:03.031  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-07-07 12:14:03.031  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 628 ms
2024-07-07 12:14:03.137  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2024-07-07 12:14:03.213  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2024-07-07 12:14:03.226  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:14:03.282  INFO 15324 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-07-07 12:14:03.285  INFO 15324 --- [           main] i.g.o.s.ScheduledDemoApplication         : Started ScheduledDemoApplication in 1.211 seconds (JVM running for 1.447)
2024-07-07 12:15:00.007  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:15:00.009  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:15:03.233  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:16:00.013  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:16:00.013  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:16:03.231  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:17:00.012  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:17:00.012  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:17:03.239  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:18:00.005  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:18:00.006  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:18:03.228  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:19:00.010  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:19:00.011  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:19:03.232  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:20:00.014  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:20:00.018  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 2-------------------10 minutes:2024-07-07T11:20:00.018052400Z
2024-07-07 12:20:00.022  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:20:00.023  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1-------------------10 minutes:2024-07-07T11:20:00.023510Z
2024-07-07 12:20:03.236  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:21:00.002  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:21:00.003  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:21:03.236  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds
2024-07-07 12:22:00.015  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 1 minute
2024-07-07 12:22:00.017  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : 60 secs
2024-07-07 12:22:03.227  INFO 15324 --- [   scheduling-1] i.g.o.s.ScheduledJobForSomething         : fixed rate 60 seconds


Thanks for your answer. So if i want to run from the boot application, how should I do ? Thanks a lot.

@TeddyKossoko did you check the example I put in references ? https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/scheduled-demo I tested with 2.2.4 same code is working.

i noticed that in the component I have 3 scheduled, this is why the latest is not run. How to tell spring to run more scheduled ?

I fix it by adding this :
spring.task.scheduling.pool.size=15

